# Regular Expression for targeting all line-height inline styles in html document

Tags: html, regex

I have a bunch of HTML articles on a Joomla based website that for better or worse (mostly worse :) have a bunch of inline styles in them. I want to remove all the inline styles that are associated with line-height as these are variant and makes the formatting ugly.

Most of these are in the format of line-height: 1.15; or 1.35; or what have you but some are line-height: normal;

Is there a regular expression that I could use to target every line-height style regardless of what comes between the : and ; in the expression. As this could technically be set to normal, a number, a length, a percentage, initial, or inherit.
Here is an example where I would want to target line-height:1.15; and remove it using a find and replace tool:

```
<li>
    <p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; text-align: justify;"><span style="background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Text to display</span>
    </p></li>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code :

```
<li>
    <p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; text-align: justify;"><span style="background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Text to display</span>
    </p></li>
<li>
    <p dir="ltr" style="top: 30; line-height: 1.35; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; text-align: justify;"><span style="background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Text to display</span>
    </p></li>
```

Regex :

```
line-height\: 1\.[13]5;
```

Output:

```
Match 1:    line-height: 1.15;      30      18
Match 2:    line-height: 1.35;     280      18
```

Comment: There is no point in using `|` in a character class if you are not going to match it as a literal. Also, `;` and `-` (outside of character class) do not have to be escaped.

Comment: Fixed second advice, but i don't get the first one.

Comment: So, would you use: `(line-height\: (\w+|\d\.\d+);)` instead?

Comment: `line-height\: 1\.[1|3]5;` will match `line-height: 1.|5`, which is why you want `line-height\: 1\.[13]5` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Direct regex-only answer:  To remove all inline line-height styles in an `s///` regex substitution:

```perl
s/(\sstyle=[\'\"])[^\'\">]+\bline-height:[^;\'\">]+;?/\1/g
```

---

That said, there are more elegant solutions.

If you're using [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), you can override the style using a [CSS3 attribute substring selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
[style*="line-height:"] { line-height:1!important; }
```

(Note, this won't work if the inline style is `!important`.)

If you're using Javascript, you can merely insert the above CSS.  With [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), use [`GM_addStyle()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle). Otherwise, do it manually:

```
var my_css = '[style*="line-height:"] { line-height:1!important; }';
var my_style = document.createElement("style");
my_style.type = "text/css";
my_style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(my_css));
document.head.appendChild(my_style);
```

This has the advantage of working for dynamically added content (and it's computationally cheaper).

If you want to do other operations with these elements in Javascript, try [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll):

```
var line_height_styled = document.querySelectorAll('[style*="line-height:"]');
for (var i = 0; i < line_height_styled.length; i++) {
  // do stuff to line_height_styled[i]
}
```